# Write data to Apache Accumulo

Tags: apache, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, accumulo, bigdata

i want to write stream data to  [accumulo](https://accumulo.apache.org)!. There is any API for accumulo to write data. It is possible in python instead of java?

Comment: Can you improve your question? It seems like the answer to this question, as it stands, could be easily obtained from either Google or Accumulo's website https://accumulo.apache.org and reading its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

See the [BatchWriter](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/BatchWriter.html) with you instantiate via [Connector](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Connector.html#createBatchWriter%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.accumulo.core.client.BatchWriterConfig%29). The Accumulo [Thrift Proxy](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/accumulo_user_manual.html#_proxy) enables non-Java clients to interact with Accumulo.

Comment: Can you please describe bit more in detail.im not getting it after alot of google.

Comment: thankx @Mike it seems intresting.ill go through it.it might be helpfull thnkyou.